# How to add a prompt's maxRetries for my bot using botbuilder SDK V4 for node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

Using the botBuilder **V3 SDK**, we used to pass a `promptOptions` object that contains the `maxRetries` value, in which we define the maximum values of repetitions of a prompt …

But, with the **V4 SDK**, I couldn't find any information in the documentation about the maxRetries.

Is there any solution or I should handle this on my own with a validator ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a v4 solution in the works that will allow you to know the number of attempts inside a validation!

You can track the progress of it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1257).

Feature slated for `4.4` Bot Framework release (April 15th)